# How to generate random prime numbers using parallel processing in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cryptography, rsa, primes

I am implementing RSA in python, and initially I'm generating prime random numbers using parallel processing by Python Multiprocessing package. I am using Miller Rabin Algorithm to check for prime numbers. This parallel implementation is supposed to run fast-er, but I can't get why this is not the case. Parallel processing is taking so much time, even for smaller prime sizes like 50 bits. Can anyone help to resolve this issue ?
(P.S. I'm a beginner to Parallel Processing)

Here is my python code (implemented functions + RSA Algorithm Implementation)

## All required Functions:

```
# Prime Generation using Parallel Processing (Miller Rabin)
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

# Prime-Generating-Functions start---
from random import randrange, getrandbits
def is_prime(n, k=128):
    # Test if n is not even.
    # But care, 2 is prime !
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n <= 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    # find r and s
    s = 0
    r = n - 1
    while r & 1 == 0:
        s += 1
        r //= 2
    flag=1
    p=Pool()
    results = [p.apply_async(primetest, args=(s,r,n,)) for x in range(k)]
    for k in results:
        output = [k.get()]
        #print("VALUE OF OUTPUT",k.get())
        if k.get()==False:
            flag=0
            break
    if flag==0:
        p.close()
        p.join()
        return False
    else:
        p.close()
        p.join()
        return True

def primetest(s,r,n):
    #for _ in range(k):
    #print("Test.value in primetest", test.value)
    a = randrange(2, n - 1)
    x = pow(a, r, n)
    if x != 1 and x != n - 1:
        j = 1
        while j < s and x != n - 1:
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == 1:
                return False
            j += 1
        if x != n - 1:
            return False
    return True

def generate_prime_candidate(length):
    # generate random bits
    p = getrandbits(length)
    # apply a mask to set MSB and LSB to 1
    p |= (1 << length - 1) | 1
    return p

def generate_prime_number(length=1024):
    p = 4
    # keep generating while the primality test fail
    while not is_prime(p, 128):
        p = generate_prime_candidate(length)
        #print("value of p is",p)
    return p
# Prime-Generating-Functions end---


# Miscellaneous Functions
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def modInverse(a, m):
    m0 = m
    y = 0
    x = 1
    if (m == 1):
        return 0
    while (a > 1):
        # q is quotient
        q = a // m
        t = m
        # m is remainder now, process
        # same as Euclid's algo
        m = a % m
        a = t
        t = y
        # Update x and y
        y = x - q * y
        x = t
    # Make x positive
    if (x < 0):
        x = x + m0
    return x
```

## RSA Algorithm starts here:

```
import time    
#key gen start----------------------------------------
start_key_gen_time = time.time()
# print("Key Generation:\n");
p = generate_prime_number(50) #Takes the size (eg 50) in bits, and generates random prime of that size
q = generate_prime_number(50)
# print("Is p=",p, "prime ? ", is_prime(p));
# print("Is q=",q,"prime ?",is_prime(q));

n = p*q; # evaluating n
# print("\nn=",n);

phi = (p-1)*(q-1); # evaluating phi
# print("phi=", phi)

e = ZZ.random_element(phi)
while (gcd(e, phi) != 1):
    e = ZZ.random_element(phi) #choosing e
# print("\ne=",e);
# print("*e < phi=",e < phi) #checking conditions for e
# print("*gcd(e,phi)=",gcd(e,phi))
# print("*Is e prime ?", is_prime(e))

d = inverse_mod(e, phi) #finding corresponding d, s.t. e*d = 1*mod(phi)
# print("\nd=",d);
# print("*Is d prime ?", is_prime(d))

# print("\npublic key = (",n,", ",e,")"); #Generated Key pairs
# print("private key = (",n,", ",d,")\n");
final_key_gen_time = time.time() 
#key gen finish------------------------------------------------

total_key_gen_time = final_key_gen_time - start_key_gen_time
print("\nTotal Key generation time taken in seconds: ", total_key_gen_time )


#Encryption start--------------------------------------------
start_encrypt_time = time.time()
# print("Encryption & Decryption:\n"); 
m = 59; #print("original msg=",m) #original message m
c = power_mod(m,e,n); #print("encrypted msg=",c) #encrypted message c
finish_encrypt_time = time.time()
#Encryption finish---------------------------------------------

total_encrypt_time = finish_encrypt_time - start_encrypt_time
print("\nTotal encrypt taken in seconds: ", total_encrypt_time )

#Decryption start----------------------------------------------
start_decrypt_time = time.time() 
decrypt_msg = power_mod(c,d,n) # decrypting 
# print("decrypted msg=",decrypt_msg)# so m was correctly decrypted
finish_decrypt_time = time.time()
#Decryption finish----------------------------------------------

total_decrypt_time = finish_decrypt_time - start_decrypt_time
print("\nTotal decrypt time taken in seconds: ", total_decrypt_time )
    
total_time_taken = total_key_gen_time + total_encrypt_time + total_decrypt_time
print("\n\nTotal algorithm time taken in seconds: ", total_time_taken)
print("\nIs decrypted msg & original msg same?", (decrypt_msg==m))
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A system, therefore your post should include a question. Please edit your post and include a real question someone could answer.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code(yet), but multiprocessing involves a certain amount of fixed overhead for each process created, so the longer-lived the process the less noticeable is the overhead.  50 bit primes are quite small and the overhead will dwarf the time needed to run the prime finding algorithm. Try testing with 2048-bit primes for a more realistic test.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I've updated the post as per your suggestions.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk , I've tried testing it with 2048-bit primes too. But now, I ain't getting any results, because of _very higher_ amount of time in comparision to 50 bits.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Your first code block only defines functions and never calls any. Your second code block is not complete. It's pretty pointless making suggestions on performance measures we don't know for code we cannot run.

Comment: You asked this question before, and my comment from before stands. You are doing way, way more work in your parallel Miller-Rabin (MR) than you would do in a serial version because *almost every* number `n` you test is composite and will fail **the very first of your 128 MR tests**, making the other 127 unnecessary.  Yes, you check for this and signal the result to the other processes but it's unlikely they receive this signal before commencing their work.

Answer (score 0):

### BEST SOLUTION

> I an unsure if I understand the concept of `Time complexity: O(sqrt(n))` and `Space complexity: O(1)` in this context but the
> function `prime(n)` is probably the `fastest way (least iterations)`
> to calculate if a number is prime number of any size.

> This probably is the BEST solution in the internet as of today 11th
> March 2022. Feedback and usage is welcome.

> This same code can be applied in any languages like C, C++, Go Lang,
> Java, .NET, Python, Rust, etc with the same logic and have performance
> benefits. It is pretty fast. I have not seen this implemented before
> and has been indigenously done.

This may help you avoid parallel processing as well. This reduces number of iterations big way.

If you are looking at the speed and performance here is the `"""BEST"""` hopeful solution I can give:

> Max iterations 16666 for n == 100000 instead of 100000 of conventional
> way

```
function prime(n) {
    
    if ((n === 2 || n === 3 || n === 5 || n === 7)) {
        return true
    }
    if (n === 1 || ((n > 7) && (n % 5 == 0 || n % 7 == 0 || n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0))) {
        return false
    }
    if ((Number.isInteger(((n - 1) / 6))) || (Number.isInteger((n + 1) / 6))) {
        for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {

            let five = (5 + (i * 6)), seven = (7 + (i * 6))
            if ((((n / five) > 1) && Number.isInteger((n / five))) || (((n / seven) > 1) && (Number.isInteger(n / seven)))) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((i * 6) > n) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Here is an analysis of all the ways of calculation:

##### Conventional way of checking for prime:

```
def isPrimeConventionalWay(n):
    count = 0
    if (n <= 1):
        return False;
    # Check from 2 to n-1
    # Max iterations 99998 for n == 100000 
    for i in range(2,n):
        # Counting Iterations
        count += 1
        if (n % i == 0):
            print("count: Prime Conventional way", count)
            return False;
    print("count: Prime Conventional way", count)
    return True;
```

##### SQUAREROOT way of checking for prime:

```
def isPrimeSquarerootWay(num):
    count = 0
    # if not is_number num return False
    if (num < 2):
        print("count: Prime Squareroot way", count)
        return False
    
    s = math.sqrt(num)
    for  i in range(2, s):
        # Counting Iterations
        count += 1
        if (num % i == 0):
            print("count: Prime Squareroot way", count)
            return False
    print("count: Prime Squareroot way", count)
    return True
```

##### OTHER WAYS:

```
def isprimeAKSWay(n):
    """Returns True if n is prime."""
    count = 0
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n == 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return False

    i = 5
    w = 2

    while i * i <= n:
        count += 1
        if n % i == 0:
            print("count: Prime AKS - Mersenne primes - Fermat's little theorem or whatever way", count)
            return False

        i += w
        w = 6 - w
    print("count: Prime AKS - Mersenne primes - Fermat's little theorem or whatever way", count)
    return True
```

##### SUGGESTED way of checking for prime:

```
def prime(n):
    count = 0
    if ((n == 2 or n == 3 or n == 5 or n == 7)):
        print("count: Prime Unconventional way", count)
        return True
    
    if (n == 1 or ((n > 7) and (n % 5 == 0 or n % 7 == 0 or n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0))):
        print("count: Prime Unconventional way", count)
        return False
    
    if (((n - 1) / 6).is_integer()) or (((n + 1) / 6).is_integer()):
        for i in range(1, n):
            # Counting Iterations
            count += 1
            five = 5 + (i * 6)
            seven = 7 + (i * 6)
            if ((((n / five) > 1) and (n / five).is_integer()) or (((n / seven) > 1) and ((n / seven).is_integer()))):
                print("count: Prime Unconventional way", count)
                return False;
            
            if ((i * 6) > n):
                # Max iterations 16666 for n == 100000 instead of 100000
                break;
            
        print("count: Prime Unconventional way", count)
        return True
    
    print("count: Prime Unconventional way", count)
    return False
```

##### Tests to compare with the traditional way of checking for prime numbers.

```
def test_primecalculations():
    count = 0
    iterations = 100000
    arr = []
    for i in range(1, iterations):
        traditional = isPrimeConventionalWay(i)
        newer = prime(i)
        if (traditional == newer):
            count = count + 1
        else:
            arr.push([traditional, newer, i])
    print("[count, iterations, arr] list: ", count, iterations, arr)
    if (count == iterations):
        return True
    return False


# print("Tests Passed: ", test_primecalculations())
```

You will see the results of count of number of iterations as below for `check of prime number: 100007`:

```
print("Is Prime 100007: ", isPrimeConventionalWay(100007))
print("Is Prime 100007: ", isPrimeSquarerootWay(100007))
print("Is Prime 100007: ", prime(100007))
print("Is Prime 100007: ", isprimeAKSWay(100007))

count: Prime Conventional way 96
Is Prime 100007:  False
count: Prime Squareroot way 96
Is Prime 100007:  False
count: Prime Unconventional way 15
Is Prime 100007:  False
count: Prime AKS - Mersenne primes - Fermat's little theorem or whatever way 32
Is Prime 100007:  False
```

Comment: @greybeard i am missing your point. what are you looking for exactly. bad me for not getting your point

Comment: changed now. it was just a simple typo issue

Comment: @greybeard right, for which two algorithms?

Comment: count: Prime `Conventional iteration way` for  `300530164787` is  `1180`, and isPrimeConventionalWay:  False; count: Prime `Squareroot way`  300530164787 is  `1180`, and isPrimeSquarerootWay:  False; count: Prime `AKS - Mersenne primes - Fermat's little theorem` way  300530164787 is  `393` (high space O[n]), and isprimeAKSWay:  False; count: Prime `Recommended way` for  300530164787 is  `196`, and prime (SUGGESTED):  False; https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-prime

Comment: will be updating the python version soon https://pypi.org/project/fast-prime/

Comment: is it worth a performance test and a publication? version : `SUGGESTED way of checking for prime:`

Comment: `is it worth a performance test` By all means! A more conventional test is to test *every* natural number up to a limit, 1000000007 has been somewhat popular. `Conventional iteration way for 300530164787 is 1180` looks conspicuously low.

Comment: `is it worth publication?` see how `SUGGESTED way` always is half of what you labelled `or whatever`. (No relation whatsoever to the names you keep dropping, just the smallest of "wheels": 2\*3. *2 \* 3 \* 5 has been somewhat popular for having 8 "prime spokes".)

Comment: (Ah, well, just noticed "conventional way" and "squareroot way" doing same number of iteration is to be expected for non-primes.)

Comment: sqroot way at the moment is what gives the least iterations (reason for - or `whatever way`) . no intent or dropping names here. `Conventional iteration way for 300530164787 is 1180 looks conspicuously low` - because it is not  prime. here is a sample check for different numbers.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-prime

Comment: The recommended way is fairly higher (relative to squareroot way/ aks way) but then the `recommended way` decreases in number of iterations when the number for check increases. recommended way.  https://github.com/ganeshkbhat/fastprimenumbers/blob/main/Fastest_Prime_Number_Calculations_codebase_python.jpeg

Comment: seemingly it even breaks a `thesis Pierre de Fermat - If N is a prime number, then bN – b is always a multiple of N, no matter what b is` which in mathematical caculations have a very high space complexity as N increases. in very rare cases, N can satisfy this condition and still be composite. some fermat text is here. https://www.quantamagazine.org/teenager-solves-stubborn-riddle-about-prime-number-look-alikes-20221013/

Comment: `names you keep dropping, just the smallest of "wheels": 2*3. *2 * 3 * 5 ` well add 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19. It makes it super fast even with AKS optimised way. something like first : `if (n == 1 or ((n > 7) and (or n % 11 == 0 or or n % 13 == 0 or or n % 15 == 0 or n % 5 == 0 or n % 7 == 0 or n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0))):` and then `for  i in range(2, math.sqrt(num)):`

Comment: or the super computer in your browser way ;-) -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stdlib/dist-datasets-primes-100k

Comment: well what are your views on the `SUGGESTED way of checking for prime:` way for a performance check and publication against `fermat` and `sqroot` and `aks` way based on the above comments. i called it fast prime - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-prime https://pypi.org/project/fast-prime/